# Is there another way to solve $\int\frac{1}{9e^v-1}dv$ that's just as efficient?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

I'm solving a DE on Paul's Notes, and I stopped at this integral:

$\int\frac{1}{9e^v-1}dv$

The suggested method is to multiply top and bottom by $e^{-v}$ to put it in a form with which a sub can be easily used.  Fair enough.

However, if I didn't know about this trick, what is another method I could have used to solve this that's about as quick?

Comment: This is pretty simple, but it's how I would probably do it: $\frac{1}{9e^t-1}=\frac{1-9e^t+9e^t}{9e^t-1}=-1+\frac{9e^t}{9e^t-1}$ and now sub $s=9e^t-1$. But it's pretty much the same as yours.

Answer (score 2):

If $\displaystyle 9e^v-1=u, 9e^vdv=du\implies dv=\frac{du}{9e^v}=\frac{du}{u+1}$

$$\int\frac{dv}{9e^v-1}=\int\frac{du}{u(u+1)}$$

Now, $$\frac1{u(u+1)}=\frac{u+1-u}{u(u+1)}=\cdots$$

Answer (score 2):

Or, along the same lines, try getting rid of the exponential by writing $v = \log x$, $dv = dx/x$, so that the integral becomes $\int \frac{dx}{x(9x-1)}$ and you're faced with the same sort of partial fraction exercise. Not much different from the previous answer, but might be what I first would have tried.

Comment: Ah, I've never seen that way before.  I like it!

Answer (score 0):

Put $s=e^v$, then $ds=e^vdv=sdv$ or $dv=\frac{ds}{s}$. The integral now is:
$$\int\frac{1}{9e^v-1}dv=\int\frac{1}{(9s-1)s}ds$$
Which is easier to solve methodly.

Comment: We were thinking the same thing -- you type faster ;)